# PHP autoload with namespaces do not load file

Tags: php, class, namespaces, autoload

I have an issue with my autoloader and namespaces.
Below the autoloader

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register( function( $class ) {

    $folder = 'include/';
    $prefix = 'class.';
    $ext    = '.php';
    
    $fullPath = $folder . $prefix . $class . $ext;
  
    if( !file_exists( $fullPath ) ){
        print 'Class file not found!';
        return false;
    }

    require_once $fullPath;
});
?>
```

Below the index file

```
<?php
require 'autoload.php';
//use backslash for namespace
$pers = new Person\Person();
?>
```

The file for the class Person is saved in the directory **root->include->Person**
I used the namespace in the class file like this

```
<?php
namespace Person;

class Person{
    function __construct(){
        print 'autoload works';
    }
}
?>
```

If I visit the index file in the browser it returns 'Class  file not found'.
Do I use the namespace correctly?

Comment: `echo $fullPath` and see if it is relevant.

Comment: What happens when you print $class value?

Comment: I don't think your auto-loader is taking namespaces into account. Your structure would need to be something like `include/class.Person\Person.php`, which doesn't seem to be your intention.

Comment: If I echo the variable $fullPath the output is **include/class.Person\Person.php**

Comment: So now, you know what is the problem. include/class.Person\Person.php doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your autoload code a little

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register( function( $class ) {

    $folder = 'include/';
    $prefix = '.class';
    $ext    = '.php';
    //replace the backslash 
    $fullPath = $folder . str_replace( "\\", '/', $class ) . $prefix . $ext;

    if( !file_exists( $fullPath ) ){
        print 'Class file not found!';
        return false;
    }
    
    require_once $fullPath;
});
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to include
Include/*class*.Person\Person.php

1. If your Os is linux, you must know that have different between / and \
2. Prefix class is exist in folder name?